# osascript command fails to Activate (open) “App Store app”.

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I’m using MacOS 10.13, connected via SSH, running as the logged in user. When I run the following command:

```
osascript -e ‘tell application “App Store” to Activate’
```

I’ve also tried:

```
open -a “App Store”
```

Results in an error:

```
32:40: execution error: File permission error. (-54)
```

This wasn’t a problem when using 10.12. Has something changed since the last update?

My end goal here is to open App Store via command line tool via SSH (ideally without using sudo command).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct quotation characters `"` (ASCII 0x22) and `'` (ASCII 0x27):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "App Store" to activate'
```

`”` (UTF-8 0xE2 0x80 0x9D) and `’` (UTF-8 0xE2 0x80 0x99) are not correct in AppleScript or Bash, respectively.

The same applies to the `open` command:

```
open -a 'App Store'
```

or

```
open -a "App Store"
```

Comment: I’ve done the correct quotations. For some odd reason, using my iPad to submit my question must of tweaked the quotes you see now.

Comment: The iPad keyboard is sometimes too intelligent. ;) I've tested all my three statements, and they are working as expected.

Comment: I’m happy to hear that. You’re on 10.13? If so, the. Why would I be getting a permission error? I’m an admin user logged in as the current user via ssh. Is there any other ideas as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Oh I see. I've tested it with 10.12. But there could be another problem when using with `ssh`: You will need a running Window Manager for the remote user. Does `32:40` points to the line with the `osascript` or `open` command? Is the remote user a regular user with home in `/Users` directory?

Comment: I wouldn’t know where to find the 32:40 as I’m just adding a one liner command in terminal. I’m not running a script. No. The user is an admin which home directory is in /private/var. when I’m logged into ssh, I am logged in as the current user. I notice that this only happens to the native apps. Third party apps seems to work. Hmm...

Comment: *File permission error.* could be a hint to a missing file or folder (e.g. `~/Library`). Have you searched for errors with Console.app of the remote machine?